# How to have opacity on a button hover that has a color dynamically set?

Tags: html, css

I have a page where the color of the button is set on page load from JavaScript. Because the color is picked by admin so I don't know what color is so can't use rgba().  Obviously, using `opacity` works but that applies to the button text too which is not ideal.  Do I have any options?

```css
button {
  font-size:3em;
}

button:hover {
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<button style="background:orange;">click me</button>
```

Comment: Do you have any code I can see?

Answer (score 0):

If the main background is known and won't change you can consider a trick using another layer on the top of your background color:

```css
a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 15px;
  font-size:30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:green;
}
a:hover {
  background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5))!important;
}
```

```html
<a href="">text</a>
<a href="" style="background-color:red;">text</a>
<a href="" style="background:blue;">text</a>
```

Comment: This is smart, but the border color doesn't change. Any other ideas?